# iTextSharp appending table to document in memory stream after PDFStamper has been used

Tags: asp.net, itext

Hi I am trying to add a table to a pdf after I have used the stamper.

```
    // CREATE MEMORY STRING 
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

    string formFile = Server.MapPath("testImg.pdf");      

    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(formFile);
    PdfStamper outStamper = new PdfStamper(reader, ms);
    AcroFields fields = outStamper.AcroFields;

    // UPDATE THE FORM FIELDS
    fields.SetField("Text1", "John Smith");
    fields.SetField("Text2", "1234567890");
    fields.SetField("Text3", "1234567890");

    //ADD LOGO
    iTextSharp.text.Image headerlogo = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(Server.MapPath("logo.jpg"));
    headerlogo.ScaleToFit(140, 399);
    headerlogo.Alignment = iTextSharp.text.Image.UNDERLYING;
    headerlogo.SetAbsolutePosition(200, 500);

    int pageCount = reader.NumberOfPages;
    PdfContentByte body = outStamper.GetOverContent(pageCount);

    body.AddImage(headerlogo);      

    outStamper.Close();

    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=test");
    Response.Buffer = true;
    Response.Clear();
    Response.OutputStream.Write(ms.GetBuffer(), 0, ms.GetBuffer().Length);
    Response.OutputStream.Flush();
    Response.End();
```

I want to be able to append the document with a table.

```
        PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(3);
        PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Header spanning 3 columns"));
        cell.Colspan = 3;
        cell.BorderWidth = 5;
        cell.HorizontalAlignment = 1; //0=Left, 1=Centre, 2=Right
        table.AddCell(cell);
        table.AddCell("Col 1 Row 1");
        table.AddCell("Col 2 Row 1");
        table.AddCell("Col 3 Row 1");
        table.AddCell("Col 1 Row 2");
        table.AddCell("Col 2 Row 2");
        table.AddCell("Col 3 Row 2");
        document.Add(table);
```

I am having trouble with defining the document to add the table to. Please can someone advise how I would add the table to the PDF in the Memory Stream.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Alex

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how you have the two pieces working together but here is how I've done it for my application.

Basically i keep the stamping separate from adding structured content and then merging the results into one big pdf. You could try and do all of it together in one big step using `table.WriteSelectedRows` (which takes a `PdfContentByte` as one of its arguments) but the time that i have to spend with manual layouts, tends to outweigh the benefit of having it all done in one step (besides the fact that it becomes one huge method which is hard to maintain / reuse)

For clarification & testing purpose, I've used FileStream but of course, the same works fine with MemoryStream and reuse streams should you end up creating one monolithic function in your development code.

Here is my test application that I used to confirm the code and run your scenario:

Steps:

1. Create Test2.pdf (stamped contents
   of original source) from Test.pdf
   (our original source)
2. Create Test3.pdf (containing all our content to be appended at the end)
3. Open Test2.pdf & Test3.pdf and merge them into Test4.pdf final stream

Note: I haven't used image stamping code and you may have to adjust `using` on `Document` in first section if `PdfStamper` closes the underlying `Document` as well (can't recall if it does from top of my head but it will throw a helpful exception in case you need to adjust the `using` statement)

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (FileStream ms = new FileStream("C:\\Test2.pdf", FileMode.Create))
        using (FileStream formFile = new FileStream("C:\\Test.pdf", FileMode.Open))
        {
            PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(formFile);
            using (Document document = new Document(reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(1)))
            {
                //PdfStamper outStamper = new PdfStamper(reader, ms);
                //PdfContentByte body = outStamper.GetOverContent(reader.NumberOfPages);

                //document.Open(); //Open document to work with

                //AcroFields fields = outStamper.AcroFields;

                //// UPDATE THE FORM FIELDS
                //fields.SetField("Text1", "John Smith");
                //fields.SetField("Text2", "1234567890");
                //fields.SetField("Text3", "1234567890");

                ////ADD LOGO
                //iTextSharp.text.Image headerlogo = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(Server.MapPath("logo.jpg"));
                //headerlogo.ScaleToFit(140, 399);
                //headerlogo.Alignment = iTextSharp.text.Image.UNDERLYING;
                //headerlogo.SetAbsolutePosition(200, 500);

                //body.AddImage(headerlogo);

                //outStamper.Close();
            }
        }

        using (FileStream ms = new FileStream("C:\\Test3.pdf", FileMode.Create))
        using (FileStream formFile = new FileStream("C:\\Test2.pdf", FileMode.Open))
        {
            PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(formFile);
            using (Document document = new Document(reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(1)))
            {
                PdfWriter pdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, ms);
                document.Open();

                PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(3);
                PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Header spanning 3 columns")) { Colspan = 3, BorderWidth = 5, HorizontalAlignment = 1 };
                table.AddCell(cell);
                table.AddCell("Col 1 Row 1");
                table.AddCell("Col 2 Row 1");
                table.AddCell("Col 3 Row 1");
                table.AddCell("Col 1 Row 2");
                table.AddCell("Col 2 Row 2");
                table.AddCell("Col 3 Row 2");

                table.CompleteRow(); //Added - table won't add the final row if its cells are incomplete - safe to have it ending a table
                document.Add(table);
            }
        }

        using (FileStream ms = new FileStream("C:\\Test4.pdf", FileMode.Create))
        using (FileStream stampedfile = new FileStream("C:\\Test2.pdf", FileMode.Open))
        using (FileStream appendfile = new FileStream("C:\\Test3.pdf", FileMode.Open))
        {
            PdfReader stampedContentReader = new PdfReader(stampedfile);
            PdfReader appendContentReader = new PdfReader(appendfile);

            using (Document document = new Document(stampedContentReader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(1)))
            {
                PdfCopy pdfCopy = new PdfCopy(document, ms);

                document.Open();

                for (int i = 1; i <= stampedContentReader.NumberOfPages; i++)
                    pdfCopy.AddPage(pdfCopy.GetImportedPage(stampedContentReader, i));

                for (int i = 1; i <= appendContentReader.NumberOfPages; i++)
                    pdfCopy.AddPage(pdfCopy.GetImportedPage(appendContentReader, i));
            }
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: You can actually skip the "save the stamped PDF to an intermediate file" stage.  1: Create the table in a PDF.  2: Open that PDF and suck your table-page into a `PdfImportedPage`.  3: Stamp it into the original PDF as you make your other changes.

Comment: Good idea. Indeed I should have done the same thing but didn't occur to me at the time. +1